# terraform does not detect changes to lambda source files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-glue

In my `main.tf` I have the following:

```
data "template_file" "lambda_script_temp_file" {
  template = "${file("../../../fn/lambda_script.py")}"
}

data "template_file" "library_temp_file" {
  template = "${file("../../../library.py")}"
}

data "template_file" "init_temp_file" {
  template = "${file("../../../__init__.py")}"
}

data "archive_file" "lambda_resources_zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "${path.module}/lambda_resources.zip"

  source {
    content   = "${data.template_file.lambda_script_temp_file.rendered}"
    filename  = "lambda_script.py"
  }

  source {
    content   = "${data.template_file.library_temp_file.rendered}"
    filename  = "library.py"
  }

  source {
    content   = "${data.template_file.init_temp_file.rendered}"
    filename  = "__init__.py"
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "MyLambdaFunction" {
  filename          = "${data.archive_file.lambda_resources_zip.output_path}"
  function_name     = "awesome_lambda"
  role              = "${var.my_role_arn}"
  handler           = "lambda_script.lambda_handler"
  runtime           = "python3.6"
  timeout           = "300"
}
```

The problem is when I modify one of the source files, say `lambda_script.py`, upon a new `terraform apply`, even though the archive file (`lambda_resources_zip`) gets updated, the lambda function's script does not get updated (the new archive file does not get uploaded).

I know that in order to avoid this, I could first run `terraform destroy` but that is not an option for my use case.

*I'm using Terraform v0.11.10

Comment: Can you confirm which version of Terraform you are using ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding the following line the resource definition:

```
source_code_hash  = "${data.archive_file.lambda_resources_zip.output_base64sha256}"
```

when the source files are modified, the hashed value will change and trigger the source file to be updated.

Comment: do you see changes when we do terraform plan? I am using the same param but I am not seeing any change when I change the source code

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me -

- add this line

```
source_hash     = "${data.archive_file.source.output_base64sha256}"
```

to `s3 lambda bucket` this will tell if any changes made.

- then add this to lambda -

```
source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.source.output_base64sha256}"
```

So your code should look like this -

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "lambda_object" {
  source_hash     = "${data.archive_file.source.output_base64sha256}"
  bucket          = "${aws_s3_bucket.s3.bucket}"
  key             = "${var.key}"
  source          = data.archive_file.source.output_path
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_" {
  function_name   = "lambda_name"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.source.output_base64sha256}"
  .......
  .......
}
```

Worked for me. Best wishes.