# Detect Ansible changes in Terraform and execute them

Tags: ansible, terraform, provisioning

I want to combine Ansible with Terraform so that Terraform creates the machines and Ansible will provision them. Using [terraform-provisioner-ansible](https://github.com/radekg/terraform-provisioner-ansible) it's possible to bring them seamlessly together. But I saw a lack of change detection, which doesn't happen when Ansible runs standalone.

**TL;DR**: How can I apply changes made in Ansible to the Terraform Ansible plugin? Or at least execute the ansible plugin on every update so that Ansible can handle this itself?

### Example use case

Consider this playbook which installs some packages

```
- name: Ansible install package test
  hosts: all
  tasks: 
  - name: Install cli tools
    become: yes
    apt:
      name: "{{ tools }}"
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      tools:
        - nnn
        - htop
```

which is integrated into Terraform using the plugin

```
resource "libvirt_domain" "ubuntu18" {
  # ...
  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    host = "192.168.2.2"
    user = "ubuntu"
    private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
  }
  provisioner "ansible" {
    plays {
      enabled = true
      become_method = "sudo"

      playbook = {
        file_path = "ansible-test.yml" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will fork fine on the first run. But later I notice some package was missing

```
- name: Ansible install package test
  hosts: all
  tasks: 
  - name: Install cli tools
    become: yes
    apt:
      name: "{{ tools }}"
      update_cache: yes
    vars:
      tools:
        - nnn
        - htop
        - vim # This is a new package
```

When running `terraform plan` I'll get `No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.` My new package `vim` will never got installed! So Ansible didn't run because if Ansible runs, it would install the new package.

The problem seems to be [the provisioner itself](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/index.html):

> Creation-time provisioners are only run during creation, not during updating or any other lifecycle. They are meant as a means to perform bootstrapping of a system.

But what is the correct way of applying updates? I tried a [`null_ressource`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/null/resource.html) with `depends_on` link to my vm ressource, but Terraform doesn't detect changes on the Ansible part, too. Seems to be a [lack of change detection](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/detecting-and-managing-drift-with-terraform) from the Terraform plugin.

In the doc I only found destroy time provisioners. But none for updates. I could destroy and re-create the machine. This would slow down things a lot. I like the Ansible aproach of checking what is presend and only apply changes which aren't already present, this seems a good way of provisioning.

### Isn't it possible to do something similar with Terraform?

With my current experience (more Ansible than Terraform), I don't see any other way as dropping the nice plugin and execute Ansible on my own. But this would also drop the nice integration. So I need to generate inventory files on my own or even by hand (which misses the automation approach in my point of view).

[source_code_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53532857/3276634) may be an option but is inflexible: When having multiple plays/roles, I need to do this by hand for every single file which keeps error-prone easily.

Answer (score 2):

### Use a `null_ressource` with pseudo trigger

The idea from [tedsmitt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56434796/3276634) uses a timestamp as trigger, which seems the only way to force a provisioner. Howver running `ansible-playbook` plain from the CLI would create overhead of maintaining the inventory by hand. You can't call the [python dynamic inventory script](https://github.com/nbering/terraform-inventory) from here since  `terraform apply` need to complete before

In my point of view, a better approach would be running the [ansible provisioner](https://github.com/radekg/terraform-provisioner-ansible) here:

```
resource "null_resource" "ansible-provisioner" {
  triggers {
      build_number = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  depends_on = ["libvirt_domain.ubuntu18"]

  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    host = "192.168.2.2"
    user = "ubuntu"
    private_key = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
  }
  provisioner "ansible" {
    plays {
      enabled = true
      become_method = "sudo"

      playbook = {
        file_path = "ansible-test.yml" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Only drawbag here is: Terraform will recognize a pseudo change everytime

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

-/+ null_resource.ansible-provisioner (new resource required)
      id:                    "3365240528326363062" => <computed> (forces new resource)
      triggers.%:            "1" => "1"
      triggers.build_number: "2019-06-04T09:32:27Z" => "2019-06-04T09:34:17Z" (forces new resource)


Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

This seems the best compromise to me, according to other workarounds avaliable.

### Run Ansible manually with dynamic inventory

Another way I found is the [dynamic inventory plugin](https://github.com/nbering/terraform-inventory), detailled description can be found [in this blog entry](https://nicholasbering.ca/tools/2018/01/08/introducing-terraform-provider-ansible/). It integrates into Terraform and let you specify ressources as inventory host, some example:

```
resource "ansible_host" "k8s" {
  inventory_hostname = "192.168.2.2"
  groups             = ["test"]
  vars = {
    ansible_user = "ubuntu"
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
  }
}
```

The Python script use this information to generate a dynamic inventory, which can be used like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/terraform.py ansible-test.yml
```

A big benefit is: It keeps your configuration DRY. Terraform has the leading configuration file, no need to also maintain separate Ansible files. And also the ability for variable usage (e.g. the inventory hostname shouldn't be hardcoded for production usage as in my example).

In my use case (Provision Rancher testcluster) the `null_ressource` approach seems better since EVERYTHING is build with a single Terraform command. No need to additionally executing Ansible. But depending on the requirements, it can be better to keep Ansible a seperate step, so I posted this as alternative.

#### Installing the plugin

When trying this solution, remember that you need to install the corresponding Terraform plugin from [here](https://github.com/nbering/terraform-provider-ansible):

```
version=0.0.4
wget https://github.com/nbering/terraform-provider-ansible/releases/download/v${version}/terraform-provider-ansible-linux_amd64.zip -O terraform-provisioner-ansible.zip
unzip terraform-provisioner-ansible.zip
chmod +x linux_amd64/*
mv linux_amd64 ~/.terraform.d/plugins
```

And also notice, that the [automated provisioner from the solution above](https://github.com/radekg/terraform-provisioner-ansible) needs to be removed first, since it has the same name (may conflict).

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question, there is no change detection in the plugin. You could implement a trigger on a null_resource so that it runs on every apply.

```
resource "null_resource" "ansible-provisioner" {
  triggers {
      build_number = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ansible-playbook ansible-test.yml"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can this be used together with [dynamic inventory plugin](https://github.com/nbering/terraform-inventory)? I tried this plugin by hand, it seems to require  `terraform apply` before the `ansible-playbook` execution. Because of this I'm unsure if it's possible to integrate the call to the python script in a Terraform ressource itself.

Comment: I haven't looked at that plugin myself, but from a quick readthrough the terraform.py script which you use as the inventory file should be callable from ```local-exec``` still. The ```local-exec``` will just behave as if you were running something from your normal cli. Definitely worth testing!

Comment: Doesn't work, but I found another way based on your approach. Posted both methods I tested

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, It works for me.

```
resource "null_resource" "ansible-swarm-setup" {
  local_file.ansible_inventory ]
  #nhu
  triggers= {
      instance_ids = join(",",openstack_compute_instance_v2.swarm-cluster-hosts[*].id)
  }
  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = var.ansible_user
    timeout = "3m"
    private_key = var.private_ssh_key
    host = local.cluster_ips[0]
  }
}
```

When it detects the changes in instance index/ids then it will triger ansible playbook.